# App layouts break when I rotate my device. Is there a fix?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

The second layout overlays the first layout only when rotating my device.  I hope there is a fix for that.

I've tried changing the Stack layout with any other layout and the result stays the same.

here is the code source

[when phone straight up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2BHx.png)
[when I rotate the iPhone the picture section is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmlJw.png)

Here is the code https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=b9hyJh&v=2

Comment: sorry here is the code  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=b9hyJh&v=2

Comment: Is this a iOS specific issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have mentioned height and widths are fixed for components. Please make it as fluid Layout by giving %height and %width

Also if your app doesn’t need landscape view. Then just turn off the landscape view. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411840/1868389

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed width and height and even took them out and still the same problem.